# Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I want my application to output logs to a the logfile in a  user's home directory.
Therefore I have configured the `log4j2.xml` file as below:

```
<Configuration>
<Properties>
    <Property name="logfolder">/${sys:user.home}/xx/log/ff</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="user_file" append="true" fileName="${logfolder}/logxyz.csv" filePattern="${logfolder}/old/$${date:yyyy-MM}/service-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.csv.gz">
        <CsvParameterLayout format="Default" nullString="" charset="UTF-8"/> 
        <Policies>
```

I can see the logs in the specified folder, however, some errors are displayed in the console:

```
ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile : java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:\Users\xx/yy/log/abc/def.csv java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:\Users\xx/yy/log/abc/def.csv
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
```

The error seems to be related to parsing the windows files system, but I've got no idea how to go about this. Will appreciate any directions. I am developing on Windows 10, but the application logging should be cross-platform.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the user I ran the program had not the permission to create the log directory and write into it. So, I just changed the owner of the working directory and restarted the program without any problem.

```
sudo chown -R runner-user:runner-user working-directory/*
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar with an environment variable.  user.home should be a fully qualified path without any prefix needed.  Example:
`user.home == C:\Users\dumbo`

Try removing the first slash from your log folder.

From:
`<Property name="logfolder">/${sys:user.home}/xx/log/ff</Property>`

To:
`<Property name="logfolder">${sys:user.home}/xx/log/ff</Property>`

Answer (score 1):

add full path to the directory according to **operating system**

if linux:

```
/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.27/webapps/My_Logs
```

if Windows: (Not Need generally append automatically )

```
   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\My_Logs
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was related with **administrator permissions** , so I just executed the Integration Studio as Administrator and the run was success

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when the running program either:

- A) does not have the permission to create the log directory and write into it or
- B) the log directory set for the program is invalid.

I'd recommend first verifying where the log directory is pointing to (is it something explicit like a C: or D: drive or trying to point to a remote location?). Once you've validated the log directory, then validate that the program has permissions to write to said directory.

Try validating your **log4j2.xml** file or **log4js config** and ensuring the path is write accessible.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error when my maven dependency pulled log4j3 beta:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>[2.15.0,)</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Checking with

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Showed it was using log4j3 beta.

I changed the dependency to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it worked again.